# What would be the difference between NOW() and DATE(NOW())?

Tags: mysql, sql, date

What is the difference between `NOW()` and `DATE(NOW())` in terms of performance, results and precision? How will MySQL understand those 2 functions?

I was wondering what is the best between

```
 WHERE the_date < NOW()
```

and

```
WHERE the_date < DATE(NOW())
```

Comment: Is `the_date` a full time stamp or simply YYYY-MM-DD?

Comment: now() will return datetime, date(now()) will return date only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NOW() returns current date/time. DATE(NOW()) returns the date part. If you want to know only the date, use CURRDATE().

Comment: actually,date(now) would extract only date part of current date. so if  now() is 2013-04-11 12:55:19 then date(now()) will return 2013-04-11

Comment: Previously I said except the Time part but I modified my reply before you did :)

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at two different comparisons.

Since `the_date` contains a time of day, the expression `the_date < NOW()` will take into account the time of day at the moment you execute the SQL statement, which could make a difference if the YYYY-MM-DD in `the_date` is the same as the current datetime.

In the case of `the_date < DATE(NOW())`, you are comparing `the_date` to `YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00000`, so the current time of day from `NOW()` is ignored and set to midnight.

What is more important here is what you need to do and what results you are expecting.

Comment: You're right, I thought both function were returning the same results. Thx

Comment: It is a subtle point, I once had a SQL bug that only showed up at 3:12 in the afternoon... because of this very reason!

Answer (score 0):

The `DateTime.Now` property returns the current date and time, for example `2011-07-01 10:09.45310`.

The `DateTime.Today` property returns the current date with the time components set to zero, for example `2011-07-01 00:00.00000`.

The `DateTime.Today` property actually returns `DateTime.Now.Date`: